# Efficient Road Network

Tags: beginner, programming-challenge, haskell, graph

## Intro

I've decided to learn [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell), because I've always enjoyed the functional aspect of Python and want to explore other languages that use this concept. I'm still stumbling in the dark most of the time, so would greatly appreciate *any* improvements.

## Description

[Challenge source](https://app.codesignal.com/arcade/graphs-arcade/kingdom-roads/)

A road system is considered efficient if it is possible to travel from any city to any other city by traversing at most 2 roads.

**Example**

For `n = 6` and `roads = [[3, 0], [0, 4], [5, 0], [2, 1], [1, 4], [2, 3], [5, 2]]`

the output should be `True`

Here's how the road system can be represented:

[image]

## Code

```
middlePoints k n roads  = [i | i <- [0..n-1], elem [k,i] roads || elem [i,k] roads]

thoughMiddlePoints k x n roads = or [(elem [points !! i,x] roads || elem [x, points !! i] roads) | i <- [0..(length points - 1)]]
    where
    points = middlePoints k n roads

reachable k x n roads = elem [k,x] roads || elem [x,k] roads || (thoughMiddlePoints k x n roads)

efficientRoadNetwork n roads = all (==True) [ all (==True)[(reachable i j n roads) | j <- [0..n-1], i /= j] | i <- [0..n-1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find `!!` and once-used definitions smelly.

A passed around environment like `roads` might as well open a scope that spans all uses of it.

```
efficientRoadNetwork roads n = and
  [ edge i j || any (\k -> edge i k && edge k j) [0..n-1]
  | i <- [0..n-1], j <- [0..i-1]
  ] where edge i j = elem [i,j] roads || elem [j,i] roads
```

Comment: Can you explain why `!!` are smelly? As said, I am still new to haskell so some explanation would be appreciated

Comment: As a heuristic from my experience, code using `!!` can usually be rewritten to be shorter and more malleable.

Comment: @Ludisposed The problem with `(!!)` is that it's _O(n)_. So for all but very small lists it's quite inefficient.

Comment: We're already linear time here, but it smells regardless.